# How to deploy Dashboard(.swf) in Android which is made in Adobe Flash Builder4.5?

Tags: android, flash-builder

all
i have created one dashboard in Adobe flash 4.5, now i want to deploy this on Android.
but i am confused as Android need .apk file to run any app. and Adobe Flash 4.5 creates .swf file.

So,,can any one please suggest or give idea how to deploy it

Thanks in Advance